# Fibonacci-type Sequence with Complex Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I have been playing around with Fibonacci-type of sequence that involve complex numbers.  I have stumbled upon the following sequence, which seemed interesting to me:
$$0,1,2i,-3,-4i,5,6i,...$$
so $F_n = 2iF_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$.  These look like a sequence of natural numbers (except for $0$) where every other is multiplied by $i$ and the signs change after two sequences.

I understand the algebra behind the above sequence, but I have been wondering whether there is an intuition behind why the sequence looks like a "modified" sequence of natural numbers.

Comment: $(X-i)^2=X^2-(2iX+1)$.

Comment: Isn't this just $n\cdot i^{n-1}$?

Comment: Also related: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166743/), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047634), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602162), [(4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403648), and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial for your recursion is $$x^2-2ix-1=(x-i)^2$$

Visibly, this has a double root at $x=i$.  Thus the general form of the solution to the recursion is $$F_n=Ai^n+Bni^n$$  Using your initial conditions it is easy to specify the solution to your case.